# GridBagLayout compnent's position not working

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

Hi  i am beginner to java and doing small GUI using GridBagLayout.  See the attached code and  also the output  .  what i want is to place the  JButtons on  top left corner   as  per the position assigned in gridx and gridy  . But it placing components in center instead of  top left as expected , if i use  Insets , gridx /gridy  all that is working but not from proper coordinates so please see attached code  and  image and guide me  about it

```
public  rect()
{     

      JPanel panel = new JPanel( new GridBagLayout());
      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      JButton nb1= new JButton("Button1  ");
      JButton nb2= new JButton("Button2  ");

      gbc.gridx=0;
      gbc.gridy=0 ;
      panel.add(nb1, gbc);
      gbc.gridx=1;
      gbc.gridy=1; 
      panel.add(nb2, gbc);
      panel.setVisible(true);
      JFrame  frame = new JFrame("Address Book "); 
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setSize(300, 300 );
      frame.add(panel);

      frame.setVisible(true); 


}
```

**OUTPUT** : want  these buttons on top left  please guide me

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is more the use of `setSize(..)`, you should rather use appropriate `LayoutManager` and call [`pack()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29) on `JFrame` instance after adding all components to `JFrame` and before setting `JFrame` visible, also no need for `panel.setVisible(..)`:

[image]

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override

        public void run() {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

            JButton nb1 = new JButton("Button1  ");
            JButton nb2 = new JButton("Button2  ");

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            panel.add(nb1, gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            panel.add(nb2, gbc);

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Address Book ");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            frame.add(panel);

            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```